# How to update session variable on dropdown change?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to update a session value by dropdown onchange event and use this session value to a second page. For this I have added following dropdown list and a submit button.On submit button press I am updating the session value.It is working sometime but most often it is giving the previous session value even after changing the dropdown list option.Whats wrong with it

```
<?php
     session_start(); // start session before output
     if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) { // some other page is posting to this page?
          // save values from other page to session
        $_SESSION['amount'] = $_POST['select_amount']; 

     }
?>


<form name="myForm"  action="/thanks" method="POST">

<table> <tr> <td style="width:272px;">
<select name="select_amount" id="select_amount" onchange="submit()">
  <option value="0">select a listing type</option>
  <option value="10">Premium Listings </option>
  <option value="20">Premium Blogs </option>
  <option value="30">1 week sticky </option>
</select></td>

 <td style="text-align:left;color:gray;"><span style="color:crimson;">*
 </span>Select a listing type</td></tr> </table>
 <table> <tr> 

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button_add" onsubmit="return 
validateForm()">

</form>
```

Comment: If you submit `onchange` in the select then you haven't submitted via the submit button so `$_POST["submit"]` won't be set. You should instead check `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST" && isset($_POST["select_amount"]))` or trigger a click to the submit button when the select changes  (that way `validateForm()` will also be called)

Comment: i removed onchange="submit()" from  <select> and now i checked. I saw that when i first time change the dropdown list it doesn't update and when i second time change the dropdown list option it shows first time changed option value.And if i change it again now it shows the second time changed option value.That means it is updating but showing after an option delay

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change session value using on change then no need to form submit, use ajax then you can do it easily

**Step1**: create your main file like this

```
<?php
session_start(); // for show your session value 
print_r($_SESSION); // remove this after check
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" action="/thanks" method="POST">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:272px;">
                <select name="select_amount" id="select_amount" onchange="update_session_value(this.value)">
                    <option value="0">select a listing type</option>
                    <option value="10">Premium Listings</option>
                    <option value="20">Premium Blogs</option>
                    <option value="30">1 week sticky</option>
                </select></td>

            <td style="text-align:left;color:gray;">
                <span style="color:crimson;">*
            </span>Select a listing type
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button_add" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

</form>

<script>
    function update_session_value(value) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/session.php', // change url as your 
            data: 'select_amount=' + value,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

then create simple session.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_POST['select_amount']) ) {
    // save values from other page to session
    $_SESSION['amount'] = $_POST['select_amount'];

}
?>
```

after on change refresh the page you can see this result

Answer (score 0):

use the ajax call on change event

```
$("#select_amount").change(function(){
var select_amount = $("#select_amount option:selected").val();
        $.post('change_session.php',{select_amount : 'store'},function(data){
            if(data != ''){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
});
```

put a php script on

> change_session.php

Comment: @Mithu you would return the data on the change_session.php page as json_encode and then that would be returned as the data variable if it was succesful.

You can check what it returns (on chrome) by going in to developer settings (F12) then going to network and selecting XHR

Comment: you can call the session in next page. thats why we are using session